# ArrayList.remove at an index does nothing

Tags: java, arraylist

Basically, when I try to remove an element from an `ArrayList` by `someList.remove(someInteger);` it does nothing, the element at that index stays there and the list is unchanged. I'm using java SE's `ArrayList` implementation. It is ensured that the list has an element at the given index. The boolean returned from the method is `false`.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet that illustrates your problem?

Comment: you probbably have `List<Integer>`

Comment: Are you sure you are doing ArrayList.remove(key) and not ArrayList.remove(value),false means it has not found such a value, does not mean a failure.

Comment: I passed Integer instead of int to the method so the wrong method got invoked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**There are two methods called `remove()`, and you're accidentally calling the wrong one.**

> The boolean returned from the method is false.

If the method is returning a boolean, then it's [this overload](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)):

```
boolean remove(Object o)
```

and not [that one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)):

```
E remove(int index)
```

In other words, it's trying to remove the object by value and not by index (presumably from an `ArrayList<Integer>` or similar).

Comment: does the remove() implementation compares the objects to check if the reference points to the actual object? unlike when using it with a primitive type?

Comment: Yes indeed, I passed an int's wrapper class, Integer instead of an int. Problem found.